# Creating a 2 x 2 matrix and finding its inverse

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, matrix-inverse

```
class multiDimensionalArray:

def __init__(self, numRows, numColumns):
    self.R = numRows
    self.C = numColumns

    self.array = [[(x+3*y) for x in range(self.R)] for y in range(self.C)]        

    self.inverse = [[]]

def modifyItem(self, row, column, item):
    self.array[row][column] = item

def getItem(self, row, column):
    print self.array[row][column]
    return self.array[row][column]

def showArray(self):
    print self.array

def changeSize(self, rows, columns):
    self.R = rows
    self.C = columns
    self.array = [[(x+3*y) for x in range(self.R)] for y in range(self.C)]

def getSize(self):
    print [self.R, self.C]
    return [self.R, self.C]

def getInverse(self):

    if ((self.R == 2) and (self.C == 2)):
        a = self.array[0][0]
        b = self.array[0][1]
        c = self.array[1][0]
        d = self.array[1][1]

        for L in self.array:
            for item in L:
                item = int(item)

        self.inverse[0][0] = d
        self.inverse[0][1] = b * (-1)
        self.inverse[1][0] = c * (-1)
        self.inverse[1][1] = a

        self.inverse = self.inverse * (1 / (a*d - b*c))
        print self.inverse
        return self.inverse


mat = multiDimensionalArray(2,2)
mat.showArray()
mat.getInverse()
```

This code gets stuck on the following lines of code. The error says "list assignment index out of range". My goal is to make this do the mathematical inverse of the given 2x2 matrix. 
Can anyone help me get it working? Thanks

```
self.inverse[0][0] = d
self.inverse[0][1] = b * (-1)
self.inverse[1][0] = c * (-1)
self.inverse[1][1] = a
```

Comment: Are you aware of numpy?  There you can do `imat = numpy.linalg.inv(mat)`.  Or maybe this is learning exercise?  Even as a learning exercise, you can take advantage of easy syntax to multiply an array by a constant, eg, `inv = inv/(a*d-b*c)`, and a multidim constructor, eg, `inv = numpy.zeros((2,2))`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two bugs.

First, you define the inverse as `self.inverse = [[]]`. It has no element `[0][0]`, hence an exception. You may write instead `self.inverse = [[0] * numColumns for i in range(numRows)]` to initialize the inverse with a zero matrix.

The program will then fail on the line `self.inverse = self.inverse * (1 / (a*d - b*c))`: Python does not know how to multiply a list by a number.
One way to do this could be

```
k = 1 / (a*d - b*c)
self.inverse = [[x * k for x in u] for u in self.inverse]
```

Notice also that `b * (-1)` can be written simply `-b`.

Apart from that, the class is a bit ugly, but the answer computed inverse is correct. I say ugly, because usually a matrix class would not initialize with a predefined constant matrix, and the inverse would be another matrix, not a member. But I guess there are only tests to prepare a better and more complete class.

---

To multiply elements of self.inverse "in place" (that is, without building a new matrix):

```
for i in range(numRows):
    for j in range(numColumns):
        self.inverse[i][j] *= k
```

You may also do this:

```
for row in self.inverse:
    for j in range(numColumns):
        row[j] *= k
```

Comment: The first part about defining self.inverse, I understand your answer.

Comment: The second part, you are just multiplying k times each element in the inverse matrix. Is that correct?

Comment: @ARW Yes, that's right. Actually this builds a new matrix (a list of list) with each element of self.inverse multiplied by k, and it replaces self.inverse. You could also multiply "in place" with for loops, I added some code to the answer to show you how.